# Slow /dev/zero format using dd with nvme to prepare crypto, is there nvme specific tool?

Tags: dd, luks, ssd, nvme, cryptography

I try to prepare an nvme for encryption, so i first follow [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403234/140938) on SO.

But the speed of dd is really really slow (less than 100 mb/s). I see there is new option to speed up dm-crypt on kernel 5.9 (see [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/jdn5vr/nvme_performance_hit_when_using_luks_encryption/)), but before updating my kernel, i want to know if using nvme-cli format zero tools is equivalent to /dev/zero to prepare a disk : https://manpages.debian.org/testing/nvme-cli/nvme-write-zeroes.1.en.html

The actual (and very very slow) command to prepare disk before luks2 format :

```
   cryptsetup plainOpen --key-file /dev/urandom /dev/nvme0n1p2 ecrypt
   dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/ecrypt bs=1M status=progress
   cryptsetup plainClose
```

*Update :*

Going to kernel 5.12 with dmcrypt 2.3.4, i use this new perf options :

```
cryptsetup plainOpen --perf-no_read_workqueue --perf-no_write_workqueue --key-file /dev/urandom /dev/nvme0n1p2 ecrypt
```

`dmsetup table` say option are correctly activated  :

```
ecrypt: 0 1999358607 crypt aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0 259:2 0 2 no_read_workqueue no_write_workqueue
```

I also verifyed that AES is activated with cpuid :

```
 cpuid | grep -i aes | sort | uniq
      AES instruction                         = true
      VAES instructions                        = false
```

I have the same problem, dd write zero at 900mb/s and slowly decrease to 45 mb/s ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer, this is much much better with oflag=direct, jumping from 45 Mb/s to 536 Mb/s :)

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/ecrypt oflag=direct bs=1M status=progress
```

Thanks to these two posts :

- [NVMe performance hit when using LUKS encryption](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615159/nvme-performance-hit-when-using-luks-encryption?rq=1)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485108/why-is-dd-with-the-direct-o-direct-flag-so-dramatically-faster